# after kubernetes preStop hook, is terminationGracePeriodSeconds still honored?

Tags: kubernetes, hook, sigterm, sigkill

I have a preStop hook for my pod that sends TSTP signals to each process, and waits for their completion, but only to a maximum of 60 seconds.

Let us say that we set `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` to 3600 seconds. After the completion of the preStop hook, shouldn't it now send the `TERM` signal to my processes, and wait until the expiry of `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` before finally sending the `KILL` signal?

Because now it seems that after the completion of the preStop hook, it immediately sends a `KILL` signal and my pod is deleted abruptly, even when there is still a process running.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't wait for the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`.

This is the intended behavior for the `preStop` hook to send a `SIGTERM` on completion.

In case the `preStop` hook isn't finished after `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` countdown, kubelet will request 2 extra seconds for it to complete and then will  send a `SIGKILL` to force the pod to shutdown.

The full sequence is :

1. pod deletion has been requested
2. `preStop` hook kicks in and `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` countdown starts :

   - if `preStop` hook completes, it sends a `SIGTERM` **which stops the pods**
   - if `preStop` hook isn't finished within `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` countdown, kubelet request 2 extra seconds before sending the `SIGKILL` **which will stops the pod**.

[image]

Sources :

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: For more context, these are sidekiq workers(ruby background processing) that I am sending TSTP signals to, and waiting for X amount of time in the preStop hook. So let us say that the sidekiq jobs are still in the middle of running when the preStop hook finishes execution.

So what is likely happening, is that my kubernetes pod responds to the SIGTERM by terminating immediately?

But my understanding is that SIGTERM is a more "graceful" termination, and there are still sidekiq jobs running at the time that the pod is terminated. Shouldn't it wait for the terminationGracePeriod to expire?

Comment: What about stoping those sidekiq processes part of the `preStop` hook ?